# How to make heat map wait for firebase data? Android

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase and the google api to make a heatmap of certain coordinates that I have stored in Firebase. My problem is that when I make the heatmap the data from Firebase has not loaded yet so the Content Provider sends an exception because there is no content in the list that I'm sending it. How do I make the heatmap wait until the list is full? I attach the code:

```
  public void addHeatMap()
{
    List<LatLng> list = null;

    // Get the data: latitude/longitude.

        list = readItems();

    // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs 


    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(list)
            .build();
    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = gmap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
}


public ArrayList<LatLng> readItems()
{

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // listas.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Alertas al = postSnapshot.getValue(Alertas.class);
                LatLng latt= new LatLng(al.getLat(),al.getLongi());
                listas.add(latt);
                System.out.println("This are coordinates"+ latt.toString());
                Log.wtf("Message", "This too: "+latt.toString());

            }
            Log.wtf("List is this", listas.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return listas;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code and move it to the end of your onDataChange function:

```
mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .data(listas)
            .build();
    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = gmap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
```

That way it won't run until Firebase returns the data.

Also notice that I changed the variable passed to the data() method inside the heatmap builder to "listas", so that it matches the variable used to hold the Firebase data.

Finally, you shouldn't return any values from readItems().  As you have seen, the function will finish executing before Firebase returns data, so it will always return an unchanged list.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel dumb that it was silly mistake